# How exactly does the Random Access Protocol detect collisions?

Tags: networking, protocols, data-transfer, random-access

Let's say that Host A is trying to transmit a frame to B and B is trying to transmit a frame to A. How does B detect a collision if A sends the frame to B right before B sends its packet to A? I've seen multiple articles refer to a "garbling of data" on the wire but what exactly constitutes that garbling?

Comment: Are you referring to CSMA/CD and suchlike? At any rate, "garbling" is simply the mix of signals transmitted by two (or more) hosts on the same physical support. Each host monitors the transmission and checks if what it reads matches what it sends. If two senders try to talk simultaneously, they will read a mix of both signals, which is pure garbage matching neither of the transmitted messages.

Comment: When you say monitor the transmission, do you mean as the frame is on its way to its receiver?

Comment: well... yes. It's as simple as listening to the channel in real time and comparing what you read with what you just wrote.

Comment: I read somewhere that it takes time= t+2d for host a to realize there's a collision, 2d being 2*propagation delay, which is why I'm a little confused.

Comment: And I appreciate your respones by the way

Comment: no problem. Indeed there is a time offset between sending and recieving : time to send one bit, then time for the bit to travel through the medium (think of a geosynchronous satellite; that would be a few hundred ms) and return as an echo to the sender.